# R: How to get max in a row and feed it's column name to a new column?

Tags: r, max

I have a dataframe as below. I want a fourth column which contains the column name of the max value in that row.

`df <- data.frame(tony=c(5,6,9), chuck=c(1,2,7), sam=c(2,9,1))`

For example, see the data below. For the first row, max value is for tony, therefore value in the 4th column is tony, and so on.

[image]

Comment: `df$maxname <- names(df)[max.col(df)]`

Comment: Yes, it does. Much Thanks. :)